# How can I modify a registry key?

Tags: winjs

I'm developing Windows 8 apps in JavaScript and in the current one I would like to modify a registry key, but how? I would like to change the background of desktop programmatically.

Comment: Can you elaborate more why you need to do that?

Answer (score 2):

From what I found MSDN, Metro Style Apps (now called Windows Store Apps) doesn't have access to the Registry.

See this:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/11f30427-e7e8-4c7f-8bed-04528c249eb6

P.S. You could probably talk more about the what you want to do so that people can help you find an alternative.